# How to avoid calling child's method from parent class in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
class Parent {
    funcA() {this.funcB();}
    funcB() {console.log('FuncB in Parent');}
  }

class Child extends Parent {
    funcA() {super.funcA();}
    funcB() {console.log('FuncB in Child');}
  }

let child = new Child();
child.funcA();
```

Problem is I get `FuncB in Child` as a result.

I want to explitly make Parent's `funcA` always call its own `funcB`, ignoring if funcB is overloaded in child classes.

I tried `this.__proto__.__proto__.funcB.call(this)` in this case, but I assume there are better ways.

Can you point me right direction?

Comment: Usually this is considered a good thing. You can work around it with `Parent.prototype.funcB.call(this)`, but that’s a bit weird. What’s this going to be used for? Maybe a private method or separate function would be better?

Comment: A situation like this is a good indication that you haven't properly thought out your object model.

Comment: a `private` you mean starting with `_` ? I am afraid I can occassionaly redefine It in one of child classes with different private method, which can break Parent's logic, and there is no any way to protect against this.

As I understand, there is a `#private` notation, but it is not yet supported well.

Comment: @Pointy, let's assume that `funcB` is some kind of pseudo-private method `_funcB`, for example `_initializeInternalDataStructure()` method. I can easily occasionally override it in one of child classes by using same quite common name for this pseudo-private function.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to deal with, but presumably there's a *reason* for the child class to override that API with its own specialized implementation. Note that `funcB()` in the child can, if it makes sense, invoke `super.funcB()`.

Comment: Are there any __checks__ or __tools__ that can warn me something like `You overrided Parent's funcB in Child class, but there is no super.funcB() in Child's funcB` ? Maybe there some kind of built-in funcionality to make such warnings in JS?

Comment: @filimonic https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/684